# offline data entry for a web application

Tags: html, caching, local-storage, offline-caching, offline-browsing

I am developing a php data-entry web application that is required to have offline data entry capabilities since it will be used in places with unstable internet. That is the users should have the option of inputing data into the system even when not online that is synchronized once they get back online.

I thought of a few ideas when it came to that

- Using HTML5 offline capabilities
- Using excel sheets and uploading them into the system

I am at lack of choice over which methodology to use, anyone have any ideas on what I can use and why? Or even ideas on any methods?

Comment: Do you have any control over the computers that will have spotty internet?

Comment: No, I will not have control over them.

Comment: How hard would it be to install a simple LAMP server on each one?

Comment: So once I install Lamp server on each one I then have them since to a remote database in the cloud? I notice that will increase my Total Cost of Ownership and given various ennvironments, will be tedious? isn't there a simpler way?